# Why are the names of some of the kauravas pointing towards evil characteristics?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, duryodhana

I don't know the names of all kauravas, but just taking the first two: Duryodhana, and Dushasana: the prefix "Duḥ" is typically used as a negative connotation (e.g. duḥkha [sorrow], durmitra [bad friend / enemy], durāchāra [opposite of established rules]).

Which parent would name their child with a name pointing towards a negative characteristic? Was this a form of "artistic liberty" used to paint the villains in a bad light? If so, what were their real names? Also - why was this literary device used (if it was at all)? For example - Śiśupāla was a villain slain by Krishna, but his name means "protector of children" which seems nice enough - definitely something that a loving parents would name their child.

Comment: Dur prefix need not always connote bad. It can also connote 'difficult'.. Durjaya - difficult to win , Durga - difficult to pass thru(invincible).Durmarshana -difficuilt to endure etc. In IIIr terms, Duryodhana -difficuilt to combat with in battle(strong warrior),(not to be understood as bad warrior).. Duhshashana-difficuilt to rule over(strong capacity to govern), ..(yodhana - battle/war), shaasana-rule/governance) so the names seems to bear a positive connotation

Comment: Oh that's very interesting; thanks for the info!